# Почему не отображаются radio button

Tags: html, css, angular, radiobutton

Я пробую сделать маленький прототип из radio buttons. На месте инициалов (Роман) будут приходить данные из backend и с помощью radiobutton я буду выбирать их.

Проблема в том, что radio button у меня вообще не отображается на странице. Скажите, в чем проблема, почему они вообще не видны?

```
<main class="similar_candidates">

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="first_user_of_similar's_user">
    Roman Dyshko
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="second_user_of_similar's_user">
    Roman Dyshko
  </label>

</main>
```

Comment: Проверил - кнопки отрисовываются и кликабельны

Comment: @SelectionForCollection Это есть разница, ли я использую Angular? Кстати, на radio button нажать невозможно. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: посмотрите ответ @humster_spb, кнопку возможно нажать. Для более точных ответов прикрепите более полный код. Тот что вы прикрепили со своей задачей справляется.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, у Вас что-то со стилями (возможно, для radiobutton где-то прописано display: none). Потому что если просто вставить Вашу разметку в сниппет, то всё отображается.

И, кстати, у всех radiobutton одной группы должно быть одинаковое имя. У Вас сейчас имена разные, поэтому корректно работать это не будет (по сути получаются checkbox с множественным выбором).

```html
<main class="similar_candidates">

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="first_user_of_similar's_user">
    Roman Dyshko
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="second_user_of_similar's_user">
    Roman Dyshko
  </label>

</main>
```

Comment: Да, у меня совсем по-другому работает. А почему невозможно нажать на radio button?

Comment: @Defender, я ж говорю - смотрите Ваши стили (также, возможно, скрипты какие-то блокируют нажатие). Угадать сложно - по разметке не определить, с ней всё ок (не считая разных имён).